# Adapter es llamado más de una vez y me genera problemas

Tags: android, android-studio, adapter

A ver si me podéis ayudar con un tema sobre los adaptadores. La verdad es que es bastante frustrante.

Tengo un adaptador que gestiona una serie de items, que son un resumen de tickets. El problema que tengo es que a veces, no siempre devuelve el mismo resultado. Por ejemplo, coloreamos algunos tickets para mostrar información adicional y a veces se colorean tickets que no deben.

Lo primero que he hecho es realizar un debug, y he visto que los resultados son inesperados cuando el adapador es llamado más de una vez. Sobre esto, he estado investigando y he leído que es un comportamiento normal, el hecho de llamar más de una vez el adapter.

Mientras realizo el debug, la primera vez sale correcto, posteriormente salen resultados inesperados. La segunda cosa que he realizado (una chapuza total) es poner variable estáticas, para que sólo entre una vez, pero sigue dando resultados inesperados.

Foto 1 (la buena):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Foto 2 (resultado inesperado):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código del adaptador:

```
public class LlistaTicketsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LlistaTicketsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

CustomField CustomField = new CustomField();
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<Ticket> tickets;

public LlistaTicketsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Ticket> tickets) {
    this.tickets = tickets;
    this.context = context;
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView icon;
    private TextView txtId;
    private TextView txtAmount;
    private TextView txtConcept;
    private TextView txtDate;
    private TextView txtResumen;
    private TextView txtAvisoExtracto;
    private TextView txtError;
    private ConstraintLayout constraintAlertMessage;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        txtId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTopRight);
        txtAmount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtBottomRight);
        txtConcept = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtBottomLeft);
        txtDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTopLeft);
        txtResumen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCentralLeft);
        txtAvisoExtracto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAviso);
        constraintAlertMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.constrainAlertMessage);
        txtError = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAlertError);

    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list_tickets, parent, false);
    return new LlistaTicketsAdapter.MyViewHolder(view);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final Ticket ticket = tickets.get(position);

    if (UApp.getMenuPermissions().isAlertHelperActive()) {

        if (!ticket.getColorCardView().isEmpty() && !ticket.getColorCardView().equalsIgnoreCase("O"))
        {
            Map<String, String> colores = UApp.getMenuPermissions().getTicketAlertColors();
            Map<String, String> obs = UApp.getMenuPermissions().getTicketAlertDescription();
            String itemColor = colores.get(ticket.getColorCardView());

            itemColor = setAlphaInColor (itemColor, 33);

            holder.constraintAlertMessage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(itemColor));
            holder.txtError.setText(obs.get(ticket.getColorCardView()));

            holder.constraintAlertMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }

}
```

Muchísimas gracias de antemano!!!! :D

---

Para solucionar el problema, antes de llamar a updateList, vuelvo a asignar el adaptador. Y para evitar problemas de sincronización, lo asigno pasado 900ms de tiempo. De este modo siempre se ve bien.

Pero lo encuentro todo demasiado difícil y complicado. Debería ser más simple...

Comment: El problema esta al momento de asignarle los datos al adapter, sube esa parte del codigo, en tus respuestas estas haciendo cosas muy extrañas.

Answer (score 0):

Increíble. Ya lo tengo casi resuelto.

Me sonaba quejas de RecyclerView, y escuché que se podía implementar un callback que se llama myDiffCallBack. Este en vez de cargar los datos de nuevo como hace adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), inspecciona las diferencias y actualiza la interfaz.

Os dejo aquí el código:

```
private class MyDiffCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback {

    ArrayList<Ticket> oldTickets;
    ArrayList<Ticket> newTickets;

    public MyDiffCallback(ArrayList<Ticket> oldTickets, ArrayList<Ticket> newTickets) {
        this.oldTickets = oldTickets;
        this.newTickets = newTickets;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return this.oldTickets.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return this.newTickets.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return oldTickets.get(oldItemPosition).getId().equals(newTickets.get(newItemPosition).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return oldTickets.get(oldItemPosition).equals(newTickets.get(newItemPosition));
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        // Puedes retornar un atributo en particular del item cambiado si quieres.
        return super.getChangePayload(oldItemPosition, newItemPosition);
    }
}
```

Y yo lo llamo de esta manera:

```
public void updateList(ArrayList<Ticket> newTicketsList) {

    DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new MyDiffCallback(this.tickets, newTicketsList));
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
}
```

Y finalmente, la función la llamo desde la misma actividad. Donde llamaría notifyDataSetChanged, llamo:

```
listAdapter.updateList(tickets);
```

Aún así, después de actualizar varias veces, la vista se me queda en blanco. ¿Alguien sabe como arreglar esto? ¿Y alguien sabe porque RecyclerView no funciona bien?

Answer (score 0):

En realidad `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, no debería provocar problemas, el problema son los datos que estas definiendo para llenar tu adapter.

**Lo que debes realizar es simplemente enviar la lista de objetos `Ticket` actualizados que deseas ver en tu `Adapter` y llamar `notifyDataSetChanged()`**.

```
public class LlistaTicketsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LlistaTicketsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

CustomField CustomField = new CustomField();
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<Ticket> tickets;

public LlistaTicketsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Ticket> tickets) {
    this.tickets = tickets;
    this.context = context;
}
...
...
}
```

Comment: La lista de tickets la actualizo una vez se descargan los tickets. Luego cada vez que se altera la lista, llamo a notifyDataSetChanged(). El problema radica en que obtengo una lista DIFERENTE de vez en cuando.